# How to get toner info from printer?

Tags: 16.04, printing, samsung

How can I get the toner info from a Samsung CLP-360 with Ubuntu 16.04.02 ? It says not supported by the printer, but in Windows, it works.

Comment: What driver are you using? Did you install the unified samsung linux driver? Or the ubuntu driver? Tried the smart panel utility from samsung?  Did you try this:http://packages.ubuntu.com/yakkety/libinklevel-dev  ?

Comment: @Rinzwind : I installed it. How can I use it ?